# Decay of $L^p$ function

Tags: functional-analysis

I have to prove that for $f \in L^p(\Bbb R^n)$ and $ϵ>0$ there exists $C>0$ such that $\int_{\Bbb R^n−B(0,C)} |f|^p~\mathrm{d}x < \epsilon^p $. Is this true and how to prove it?

Comment: Prove it for simple functions, which are dense, and extend using the triangle inequality.

Comment: I have moved remaining questions to the separate question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867448/can-i-control-lebesque-integral-by-integration-over-small-sets since the first question has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g_n(x) =  1_{\|x\|\ge n}(x)|f(x)|^p$ and $g = |f|^p$. Then $g_n\le g$ and $g-g_n \uparrow g$ point-wise and $g$ is integrable. So by monotone convergence theorem one have that $\int g{\rm d}x-\int g_n{\rm d}x = \int g-g_n{\rm d}x \uparrow \int g {\rm d}x$ and therefore $\int g_n {\rm d}x\downarrow 0$. So for some $n$, one have that 
$$
\epsilon^p\ge \int g_n = \int 1_{\|x\|\ge n}(x)|f(x)|^p {\rm d}x.
$$